# Can the US Government assert copyright on a government work internationally?

Tags: copyright, public-domain, us-federal-government

From what I understand, large swaths of US Government works are considered  "public domain", but this unrestricted status applies only *within the United States*,

For this question I am assuming the work is unambiguously a US Federal Government work that would otherwise be public domain to someone within the US.

Can the US Government claim copyright to this work internationally?

and optionally:

Has there ever been an instance of the US Government defending the copyright of such a work internationally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to CENDI](https://www.cendi.gov/publications/FAQ_Copyright_30jan18.html#_Toc505089933), yes the US government is able to claim copyright on works internationally.

The law in question which makes US government works public domain in the US ([17 U.S. Code § 105](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/105)) only does so within the confines of US copyright. Since copyright protection is on a per-country basis, there's no reason that the US government couldn't assert IP rights under foreign copyright law (though I didn't go looking for an example).

While the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) generally requires countries to provide foreign works the same protection as domestic works, I can think of two general reasons why US government works wouldn't fall under copyright protection in some countries:

- The country simply doesn't apply copyright protection to any government works (don't know how common this is).
- The country applies the [rule of the shorter term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_the_shorter_term). If they do, they aren't required to provide a longer term of protection than the country of origin does (which is nil in this case).